# Is "on the average" correct?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I just heard it on radio, but I am pretty sure that "on the average" is incorrect.

> On the average, the prices for cars will increase by 2 494$ if the tariffs
>   against auto imports is implemented.

Comment: Do you mean 'the price of a car'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a point of difference between English dialects. I think most dialects used for formal registers would not use *the* there, at least not in the formal register. However, if we are talking about an informal register, there are dialects where this is common. As tends to happen, this also means that, in some dialects, it is gradually becoming more acceptable in more formal registers.

Comment: Collins Dictionary says that "on the average" is idiomatic for "usually, typically".

Comment: Perhaps in some dialects... it's also used for an actual average, in my experience, in some. Maybe the same ones, I don't know. The quote in the OP sounds like it's referring to an actual average to me.

Comment: Definitely not standard, but hardly unheard of.